# Is it inappropriate to ask moderator to share details related to my comment's edit history (when it was edited by a mod/staff)?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, moderation

One of my comments which I did not edit had the pencil symbol beside it and the tooltip mentioned "this comment was edited one time". So, it is obvious that some moderator or staff edited my comment.

I wanted to see the edit history of the comment but obviously it is not possible for normal users to see it as SE didn't give us that feature yet. So, I asked a moderator (in chat) about the edit history of my comment, and the moderator declined my request (I'm not gonna comment about what the moderator did was right or wrong).

I just wanted to know if it is inappropriate to ask such stuff to a moderator. Also, the comment did not have anything abusive (if that was the case, I wouldn't ask a moderator the edit history of it).

Comment: You're usually free to ask, don't be surprised to get "No" for an answer though.

Comment: Did you provide the mod in chat with the comment's link?

Comment: The contents of a comment history are not easily copied (it's in a popup that disappears upon the next interaction with the page, including upon text selection). It's likely that the easiest thing for the moderator to do would be to take a screenshot, but then the screenshot would need to be edited, at least to crop it, potentially needing things anonymized and/or private information removed. Overall, your (not very well defined) request is, potentially, asking for a non-trivial amount of time and effort on the part of the moderator.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні Yes, I did provide the comment link to the mod in chat.

Comment: If the comment was posted on SO I think you'll have little chance of knowing what happened. If it was posted on a site which struggles to attract 20 posts per day, I don't see how the moderator=editor could be strapped for time to explain. It's part and parcel of being a moderator IMO. They are volunteers serving the community, it's not the other way round. Now if it was a CM that would be different, a bit like expecting your manager to explain why he/she wants to hold a meeting first thing on Monday morning when everyone agreed on Tuesday. You just have to trust their judgement.

Comment: I experimented. It *is* in fact rather annoying to take screenshots of comment edits

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні The comment was not posted on SO. It was posted on a meta site.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Windows key + Shift key + S?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek but a mod could look at the edit history and see what had been modified, understand what led to the moderator's decision and without screenshots, simply explain to the user.

Comment: @Mari-Lou that would take even more time and effort.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard are you or have you ever been a moderator? If you have direct experience then say so. When I look at the edit history of a post, sometimes there is a single edit sometimes it can be as many as 40. How many times can a comment be edited? At the most ten, and that's exaggerating.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard in the OP's case the comment was edited only once. It's one edit. Is it complicated for a moderator to check the edit history when it has been modified once?

Comment: @Mari-Lou how is it related? I compare bunch of actions that I can do myself against bunch of actions I can also do. Bunch #1 is: looking at revisions, and analyze them to understand what has changed and why. Bunch #2 is: taking screenshot, and crop. #2 would take less time and effort for me for certain, even for trivial edits. Can't speak for others, that's true, but just figure that just the act of analyzing might take more mental effort than few button clicks to crop the screenshot. And when the edit is subtle, even harder to know why it was done. (Unless of course it's the mod doing it.)

Comment: @Mari-Lou as for OP case, the question is, or should be, generic, about the general case, which can be more complicated.

Comment: I mentioned elsewhere the request for a screen shot seems excessive, sorry I should have included that reflection. I am focusing on the reason for the edit, it must been fairly banal, and therefore easy to identity. If the mod being asked is *not* the editor I can understand why they might not want to get involved but if they looked at the comment history wouldn't the editor's name appear? I don't know.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні The moderator confirmed that they did not edit my comment.

Comment: *"If the comment was posted on SO I think you'll have little chance of knowing what happened."* That's not true, @Mari-Lou. Several of us SO mods pay close attention to Meta Stack Overflow, and we would be happy to answer a respectful inquiry. That said, I agree that it's generally more work than is necessary, as Makyen already noted, *and* I wholeheartedly agree with Zanna that this info should just be shown to the user directly. I don't know why it's hidden. I can understand not building out a new feature that does this, but a great one already exists.

Comment: @CodyGray I know that you are very active on SO meta, but there are 24 other elected moderators and I may have seen not more than five moderators actually posting answers or commenting on meta. This tells me that either the other mods occupy themselves with other issues, working silently in the background, or that they lack the physical time to respond. There's also a 3rd option: They're just not interested but why would they carry on being a mod if that were true? Anyway, if someone asked any of the "less" active mods ***in chat***, I wouldn't be surprised if they brushed aside the request.

Answer (score 14):

The real issue is that the system brokenly obscures a comment's edit history from the author of the comment, which is especially bad in a situation where the author can't edit a comment after the grace period, but moderators can.

We all hope that moderators will use their power responsibly :) but if someone changes my words, I at least want to know who and how.

As mentioned by others, it might take longer than five seconds to get the information ready (I wish it were easier to post screenshots to chat), and mods shouldn't have to do this work because the edit history should just be available to you, so I would not say that mods should feel obliged to provide it, but I do think that providing it is morally right.

Answer (score 11):

To answer that, one needs to define what "appropriate" means. There are several components that constitute the appropriateness of such a request on the network:

1. [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service), [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), and [Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy).
2. [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement).
3. Community policies.
4. Handling moderator stance.
5. Etiquette considerations.

The nature of the request surely falls under being appropriate according to the ToS, CoC, and AUP. The MA appropriateness is a bit more complex. Moderators have access to information that isn't exposed to common users of the network, that includes the comment edit history. However, it is doubtful that the latter violates section VI of the agreement to serve as a basis of the decline.

When no legal considerations are applicable, appropriateness is governed by established community policies commonly found in Meta FAQs and various user posts. As far as I am aware, there are no existing policies on revealing such information to users.

When there are no established community policies, appropriateness comes down to a judgement call of the moderator handling the case. In the case of requesting information not available to common users but not constituting a violation of the MA, they may or may not consider the request appropriate based on the circumstances and / or their overall views.

Lacking all of the above, the only one able to determine appropriateness is you and your understanding of the proper etiquette. In my humble opinion, asking a moderator to review your comment history out of pure curiosity isn't the best use of limited moderator time, and is better reserved to cases where knowing the previous revision is important.

That said, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong in just *asking* a moderator to do so, provided you are prepared to cease and desist if the request is declined and not insisting that the moderator discloses this information.

Comment: I hope SE staff can let us know if sharing comment edit history to the OP of the comment is considered as violation of Moderator Agreement.

Comment: @RandomPerson well, likely not, but the section VI is, as usual with legal documents, is written to allow a lot of leeway in interpretation of it entails, so yeah, it would be interesting to know what SE's position is, generalised, on mods revealing information that is not supposed to be seen by common users but doesn't necessarily constitute PII exposure.

Comment: "… *isn't the best use of limited moderator time* …" some sites are notoriously less busy than SO, Ubuntu, SuperUser or Mathematics. The OP has clarified that the edited comment was not posted on SO.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні correct, however, that doesn't mean it's a good use of kod time even if they aren't particularly busy. That said, as per the following statement, I don't find anything inappropriate in asking a mod to expose the information at their discretion. To be frank, I am firmly in the camp that believes that normal users should be able to see the edit history of comments - that would save everyone the trouble.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine What is "kod"?

Comment: @RandomPerson a perfect example of when a mod might intervene and fix a typo kod = mod

Answer (score 8):

My two cents, as ordinary long time user.

- It is appropriate to ask, however it is also appropriate for the moderator to ignore or decline the request.
- Comments are minor, people really put too much thought and emotion into them sometimes.
- Most likely the comment was edited to fix some typo, if it wasn't abusive as you say.

If you feel like it, you have full right to delete the comment, no harm done. But I think you shouldn't try to see what has changed again, if it was important, mod would have let you know already. (e.g. if you were somehow rude without meaning it, perhaps.)

Comment: "*however it is **also appropriate for the moderator to ignore or decline the request***." I couldn't disagree more strongly. Any moderator ignoring a *simple request* (not a personal attack) I find super annoying and super rude, it still happens to me on EL&U, it used to happened on  ELL but today ALL the mods are generally more polite, but it rarely, if ever, happens on Meta.

Comment: @Mari-Lou well so we have very different definition of moderators and what their role is. It's fine, and also fine to disagree. And I really don't think that "Sorry, I can't fulfil your request" is rude in any way, not even a tiny bit.

Comment: That's not ignoring, that's replying.

Comment: Well, ignoring isn't very nice, true, but also not rude when we understand it's simply not part of their job. We don't need nice moderators, we need moderators who are good in what they're doing.

Comment: If we are expected and asked to be nice to another, see the CoC and see those wavy hands under new contributors' cards, why should moderators be any less?

Comment: It's about being nice when interacting. The CoC does not force people to interact, e.g. it does not say one must explain downvotes, which many people find as rude and even worse. But once a user choose to interact with other user, they must do it in a polite way. Moderator who is rude **when interacting with other user** is indeed breaking the rules and should be handled with.

Comment: Being nice is exactly about interacting with our fellow beings. I suppose you belong firmly in the camp which argue that words such as "Hello", "Thank you" and "Please" are unimportant,  and add unnecessary noise to content. But in the real world, these trivial pleasantries help oil the wheels of society, and helps us get along with one another. If we get along, we help each other, if we help each other we start feeling good about ourselves. EDITED OK! I see your edited comment and I agree! :)

Comment: Actually, I don't belong to any camp. Those words are super important in the real world, sure, and in social networks, but SE is neither of those.

Comment: I agree with @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні that for transparency, if a mod edit he should be able to comment why if needed, but it's IMO reaally low priority stuff. IMO It can however backfire to the OP as the mod maybe edited to remove semi-agressive text that got flagged, and didnt sent a notice if the user was borderline. That would force the mod to put the fact to the user. I never editied to remove typo or Hello/Hi, etc.. and most of thank you comment just got erased, an edit for a comment is more strange there.

Answer (score 3):

Next time a question in chat leaves you wondering about the appropriateness of what you did, just ask the moderator you're dealing with. They have all the context to decide if they would be willing to receive further chat requests like this from you.

Anything users will say here will not be able to take into account that context, and as such even if you get a yes or no here, in practice it will mean nothing. The only way to get a definitive look into this moderator's thoughts would've been to ask them. Also, it would've probably been ten or more times faster if you're already having a chat conversation to ask in that conversation, instead of writing up a MSE post.

Comment: Asking the moderator for further details may be seen by them as being pushy or bossy when something doesn't go one's preferred way. While the only true way to know why one's declining to do something is to ask them directly, I can see why someone would opt to post here as to whether their action is appropriate or not so that in case it's not generally a good thing to do, they'd know in advance so they don't make a mistake in interacting.

Comment: As I said in the post @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog : only the moderator involved will have full context, and will be able to give a definitive opinion on any behavior. If you do expect based upon previous interactions you will be seen as pushy or bossy, it's better to not ask in chat or at the very least come clean and include a history of this in your meta posts. I doubt it would be seem as less pushy to ask random uninvolved strangers on a different site. If we say this was fine, and the mod found it not okay because they have more context, all you've succeeded in doing was cause more trouble.

Comment: Also, there is asking and there is asking... By all means if one does decide to ask, they should be smart enough to ask in such a way as to avoid  being demanding or entitled. Again, only the user and moderator involved will (and should) have the full context and control over their interactions.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell The moderator did explain their position by stating that they would not delve into anyone's edit history.

Comment: @RandomPerson well, there you have your answer. Asking this mod to disclose anyone's edit history again would be inappropriate then, as they have given you a clear signal future requests like it of them would be unwanted.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell So you mean I can ask some other moderator regarding the edit history of my comment?

Comment: @RandomPerson That's up to the moderator that has full context to answer, not me. They know whether their remark was intended to say 'never do this with anyone ever again' or 'we're too busy a site to take requests like these' or 'it's fine to ask someone else in chat' or 'don't ever ask in chat, use a flag' or whatever. I can't determine subtext, but at least from what you said there's a black-on-white confirmation that this mod doesn't delve into anyone's edit history, which means asking them again would be inappropriate as they've already said they don't delve into *anyone's* edit history.

Comment: Again, communication here will be key, and you could've had an answer already if you had asked the right person.

Comment: If a site has four moderators and I know for a fact that my comment has been edited, let's say the edit is really small. How would I know which moderator edited the comment? Asking one of the four moderators on chat seems the ideal place to make an informal inquiry. Posting about it on the sister meta could seem to be accusatory, don't you think? After all where's the harm in hearing "Oh, it was just a spelling fix" or "I fixed the user's name, clarified the date, removed the error” etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні This answer starts with *'Next time a question in chat leaves you wondering about the appropriateness of what you did,'* not with 'Never dare to ask a mod a question in chat ever again'.

Comment: But if anyone feels any potential question may be deemed 'inappropriate' by the one they want to ask that question, without having asked the same question before, my advice still stands: Communicate with the one you are wanting to ask the question about whether your question is appropriate to ask them. They have all the context, it's faster and the answer will be more useful than opinions of random others on another site.

Comment: But you are a moderator on two sites, you *know* if checking the edit history of a comment is a pain (probably is) or if it just takes a few seconds. I agree asking for a screenshot is a bit much to ask, but the user could still have some sort of resolution.  I always find edited comments by a 3rd party to be super creepy and invasive. It comes as bit of a shock, can you sympathise with that sentiment?

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні I fail to see how my sentiments on the creepiness/invasiveness of edited comments are relevant to a question that quite simply asks "Is it appropriate to ask a moderator in chat to share the edit history of a comment of mine". And that question I answered by saying "ask the moderator, they have all the context necessary to answer whether the request was deemed inappropriate".

Comment: Context that could include things like 'this user is causing a massive moderation load by asking about every simple thing, at some point that has to stop', 'we're too busy for that', or 'use flags, not chat comments so it can be handled by the right person'. I'm not going to say it's always appropriate or inappropriate to ask, without such context.