# Please make the revision histories of comments visible to their authors

Tags: feature-request, comments, revisions-list, comment-edits

When one posts a comment, one is able to edit it during a brief grace period. Moderators can edit any comment at any time.

A comment that has been edited will have a little pencil symbol:

[image: comment clip with pencil symbol at the end circled badly]

Moderators can view the revision history of a comment by clicking the pencil. It looks like this:

[image: very boring revision history of comment shown in an internal window that lies on top]

What I'm requesting in this post is for this revision history to also be accessible to the author of the comment, as well as to mods.

While comment edits by moderators are uncommon, and we trust moderators to use this ability responsibly, it seems reasonable that the original owner would be able to see edits to their own comment.

Comment: Related: [Is it inappropriate to ask moderator to share details related to my comment's edit history (when it was edited by a mod/staff)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381431/348196)

Comment: Also related, previous requests to show such history to regular users: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239340/369802 from 2014 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318219/369802 from 2018.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell One key differentiator between those requests and this one is that this one is asking to make the revision history available to the _author_ of the comment, exclusively (amongst non-mod users).

Comment: @41686d6564 hence the related but no dupe vote. But as far as I'm concerned, the same reasoning used to decline those requests can be applied to this post. Comments are second-class citizens, they are temporary, and don't deserve much attention. Adding a history will also achieve next to nothing besides more incentive for drama: The original author can't roll anything back, so at best it will only give you more drama in flags or on meta that distracts the focus from what this site is really about: Q&A.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell giving it some thought, those who really interested to know why their comment was changed would raise more drama if they'll have no way to do it. So better let them see, and it's not common enough to really impact the flags queue.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Showing a revision history doesn't show you *why* a comment was changed, it just shows *what* was changed. So saying this would stop the ones that want to know *why* their comment was changed is simply not true. Again, comments are temporary second-class citizens that don't deserve much attention to begin with, which is why editing them in the first place is already a bad idea.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I think more "drama" can happen in chat... also, edit history is available to everyone in chat.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell well, I disagree, and also never said it will stop the drama, just lessen (?) it. :-)

Comment: @RandomPerson everyone with sufficient reputation can handle some chat flags, not just moderators. Reasoning for showing that could then be similar to reasoning as outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277193/369802): You may need the revision history to see if an innocent looking message wasn't some slur before. No regular user can moderate comment flags (or even raise flags on their own comments), so they don't need revision histories for similar reasons.

Comment: As for everyone saying "comments are temporary second-class citizens" (including me many times!) well, over time I learned that enough people care for comments very much, so maybe this should be re-considered as a whole as well. @Tink

Comment: While I agree that comments are "second class citizens", at least they are definitely that way on SO, there are some main SE sites where they are considered substantially more important. It's also the case that they tend to be notably more important on Meta sites where the comments can be a *substantial* part of the discussion. For child meta sites, this is because we shoehorn in "discussions" into SE's Q&A format, into which discussions don't fit all that well. Yes, even on such sites, comments are substantially less important, but they are not meaningless.

Comment: if a moderator deigns to edit a comment, I suppose that comment isn't so very unimportant

Comment: All these comments about comments being unimportant are as irrelevant as they are ironic. Aside from how tired I've grown of that oft-repeatedly and mostly-incorrect claim, the more important fact is that **this feature already exists**. I could completely understand if the claim were that it's not worth developer time to implement a revision history for comments because of comments' *relative* unimportance. But that's not what we're talking about. The feature already exists, it works extremely well, but it is only shown to mods. We just need a dev to flip a switch to show it to authors.